# Atom: Setting up Hydrogen Launcher for use with Python 3.7

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter, atom-editor, hydrogen

I am trying to set up Atom to be able to run Python code interactively and on a line-by-line basis, and have been trying to work with Hydrogen and its associated packages to that end. The Hydrogen package is working properly as intended, as I'm able to run the script on a cell-by-cell basis, and am able to choose which Python kernel to run the script with.

However, the problem starts when I try to run it with Hydrogen Launcher, which is supposed to enable you to launch Jupyter consoles connected to Hydrogen either via the computer's terminal, or inside PlatformIO IDE Terminal in Atom. I have installed PlatformIO IDE Terminal, and it is running correctly on its own, but when I try to launch a Jupyter Console either on its own or in the PlatformIO IDE Terminal, I get the following input in the terminal, followed by the subsequent list of errors:

```
TERMINAL (WINDOWS POWERSHELL) ENTRY:
>>> jupyter console --existing C:\Users\mcli2et2\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\runtime\kernel-a0e2fc80-141e-4f67-ac63-0f15feed2b4e.json

ERROR MESSAGE:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-console-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from jupyter_console.app import main
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_console\app.py", line 22, in <module>
    from jupyter_client.consoleapp import (
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .connect import *
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 24, in <module>
    import zmq
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
    from zmq import backend
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    reraise(*exc_info)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\utils\sixcerpt.py", line 34, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    _ns = select_backend(first)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\select.py", line 28, in select_backend
    mod = __import__(name, fromlist=public_api)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import (constants, error, message, context,
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Could you advise me on what might be preventing the Jupyter console from running? I use Windows 10, and am running two Python environments at the moment: the base one packaged with Anaconda that is kept up-to-date relative to Anaconda, and a separate one for HyperSpy that is kept up-to-date relative to the HyperSpy package packaged by conda-forge. Both Python kernels can be successfully run on Jupyter Notebook when opened via Anaconda Prompt or even Command Prompt.

Thanks!